# gulp v4 function async task does not finish executing

Tags: javascript, gulp

I am working with v4 gulp and converting my tasks to functions. I have a simple clean function that executes a parallel task.

```
const clean_server = () => del('build/server/*');
const clean_client = () => del('build/client/*');

export function clean(done) {
  gulp.parallel(clean_server, clean_client);
  done();
}
```

When I call `done()` the way I'm calling above, which is also suggested from the docs https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/creating-tasks, I see the task get initiated, however, it doesn't actually complete the task.

However, when I change it to:

```
export function clean(done) {
  gulp.parallel(clean_server, clean_client)(done);
}
```

This way works.

So my question is,  why doesn't the first way as suggested by the docs complete the async task?

Answer (score 0):

Because `done` must be passed as a callback to `parallel`. Either like the way you did on or like the following

```js
gulp.parallel(done => {
  clean_server()
  clean_client();
  done();
})
```